# Overriding Groovy metaclass invokeMethod with a curried closure

Tags: groovy, closures, metaprogramming

Groovy allows us to [override per-instance invokeMethod](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-metaprogramming.html#_groovyinterceptable) with a closure via the object metaclass. This works as expected with regular closures, but when I tried the same thing with a [curried closure](https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_currying) I ran into a problem: the override doesn't work.

```java
// Create closures
def invokeClosure1 = { String name, Object args ->
    name
}
def invokeClosure2 = { String suffix, String name, Object args ->
    "${name}$suffix"
}
def invokeClosure2Curried = invokeClosure2.curry('!')
assert invokeClosure2Curried.parameterTypes as List == [String, Object]

// Test closures
assert invokeClosure1('foo', null) == 'foo'
assert invokeClosure2Curried('foo', null) == 'foo!'

// Create an object
def s = 'Hello'
assert s.toUpperCase() == 'HELLO'

// Override instance metaclass invokeMethod with a regular closure
s.metaClass.invokeMethod = invokeClosure1
assert s.toUpperCase() == 'toUpperCase'

// Override instance metaclass invokeMethod with a curried closure
s.metaClass.invokeMethod = invokeClosure2Curried
assert s.toUpperCase() == 'toUpperCase!'
```

Output:

```
assert s.toUpperCase() == 'toUpperCase!'
       | |             |
       | 'toUpperCase' false
       'Hello'
```

The last assertion fails. Am I doing something wrong here?